# Shared angular modules not landing in webpack common chunk

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli, code-splitting

I have a lot of angular modules that are reused in the entire application, e.g.

- I18nModule
- StringInputModule
- ...

After building the app via angular CLI and inspecting the bundle with webpack bundle analyzer, these shared modules pop up in different modules that include them. Is there a way to force them into the `common` chunk instead? Or what are possible mistakes that can result into this behaviour of code duplication instead of detecting that it is indeed a shared module.

To clarify: the common chunk exists, but only a handfull of ~ 50 shared modules are actually bundled within that chunk. The rest is either duplicated across different feature chunks or a lot of them are within the first feature page module.

AoT is enabled, so is the `commonChunk` option (https://angular.io/cli/build)

Comment: Try importing it in appmodule

Comment: unfortunately that did not help

Comment: I was wondering the exact same thing. In my case this happens to some material components. Did you find a solution/explanation for this?

Comment: unfortunatly not

Answer (score -1):

You can create a sharedModule where all of your reusable component are and then import that module in appmodule of import sharedModule when ever you need those
Ex:

$ng g m shared --routing

$ ng g c shared/components/shared --module shared

**shared.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";

import { SharedRoutingModule } from "./shared-routing.module";
import { SharedComponent } from "./components/shared/shared.component";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [SharedComponent],
  imports: [CommonModule, SharedRoutingModule],
  exports: [SharedComponent]
})
export class SharedModule {}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";

import { AppRoutingModule } from "./app-routing.module";
import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import { SharedModule } from "./shared/shared.module";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, AppRoutingModule, SharedModule],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**first.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";

import { ExampleRoutingModule } from "./example-routing.module";
import { ExampleComponent } from "./components/example/example.component";
import { SharedModule } from "../shared/shared.module";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ExampleComponent],
  imports: [CommonModule, ExampleRoutingModule, SharedModule]
})
export class ExampleModule {}
```